# Merge duplicate cells in a datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a list of an object that i show in a `lightning-datatable` that has some duplicate values in the first column, like this:

[image]

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) 
 public static List<Asset> getAsset(Id recordId) {
     return [SELECT Id,Name,Product_Family__c,Type__c FROM Asset WHERE License__c =:recordId];
 }
```

js:

```
@wire(getAsset, { recordId: '$recordId'})
getAsset({data, error}) {
    if(data) {
        this.assetsList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        this.error = undefined;
    }
    else if (error) {
        this.showError(error);
        this.assetsList = undefined;
    }
}
```

html:

```
 <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={assetTest}
            hide-checkbox-column="true"
            columns={columns}>
 </lightning-datatable>
```

I want to be able to merge the duplicate values from the first row and show it like this:

[image]

How can i do this using datatable? and if not with datatable, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, there is no option to achieve this using the standard `lightning-datatable` component.
But you can achieve the same using a custom table and SLDS. You will need to prepare your data in such a way that all other rows are grouped up basis Product Family.

Based on number rows in each Product family you can define the row span in `td` attribute of Table.

I have created a sample table in [this](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/p6LI1RTN6vlxrGv3UOwf) playground.

So whenever data is returned from the apex/wired method you need to process it and group basis product family. See the below code. I have used a simple hardcoded products list to demonstrate the example.

```js
   get productArray() {
       let samples = [
           {
               family: 'Family 1',
               assetName: 'Name 1',
               assetType: 'Type 1'
           },
           {
               family: 'Family 1',
               assetName: 'Name 2',
               assetType: 'Type 2'
           },
           {
               family: 'Family 1',
               assetName: 'Name 3',
               assetType: 'Type 3'
           },
           {
               family: 'Family 2',
               assetName: 'Name 4',
               assetType: 'Type 4'
           },
           {
               family: 'Family 2',
               assetName: 'Name 5',
               assetType: 'Type 5'
           },
           {
               family: 'Family 3',
               assetName: 'Name 6',
               assetType: 'Type 6'
           }
       ];
       
       // building a map here basis family
       let groupedDataMap = new Map();
       samples.forEach(product => {
           if (groupedDataMap.has(product.family)) {
               groupedDataMap.get(product.family).products.push(product);
           } else {
               let newProduct = {};
               newProduct.family = product.family;
               newProduct.products = [product];
               groupedDataMap.set(product.family, newProduct);
           }
       });

       // building a products list wrapper of eg { rowspan : N, products: [], family: 'sample family'}
       let itr = groupedDataMap.values();
       let productArray = [];
       let result = itr.next();
       while (!result.done) {
           result.value.rowspan = result.value.products.length + 1;
           productArray.push(result.value);
           result = itr.next();
       }
       return productArray;
   }
```

Here is the code for HTML.

```html
<tbody>
    <template if:true={productArray}>
        <template for:each={productArray} for:item="family">
            <tr key={family.family} class="slds-hint-parent">
                <td data-label="family" rowspan={family.rowspan}>
                    {family.family}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <template for:each={family.products} for:item="product">
                <tr key={product.assetName}>
                    <td key={product.assetName} data-label="family">
                        {product.assetName}
                    </td>
                    <td key={product.assetName} data-label="family">
                        {product.assetType}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </template>
    </template>
</tbody>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: how to fix width of the column ? if the content is large, the table is expanding, I want to set the width of the column with predefined size

Comment: @brahmajitammana Just set the fixed width of the column header and enable word-wrap.

Answer (score 1):

instead of rowspan and colspan, that is not supported by lightning:datatable
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable

You can use "cellAttributes" & css to perform border cell border appearance

```
var tableColumn = { 
            "label": sampleRow.fieldLabels[fieldName],
            "fieldName": fieldName,
            "type": sampleRow.fieldTypes[fieldName],
            "sortable": true,
            "cellAttributes" : {"class":{"fieldName": fieldName + "-css" }}
};
```

Comment: do you have any example of this ?